# Field extensions ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been recently set the following question:

Let $K \subset F $ be a field extension, $P(X)\in K[X]$ a polynomial of degree $d$ with $d$ distinct roots $\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{d}$. Show that the degree of $K(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{d})$ over $K$ is at most $d$!

I simply do not quite understand what the difference between $K[X]$ and $K(X)$ is, nor do I understand what exactly $K(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{d})$ is. If someone could help clarify what exactly these things mean, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The quotient field of $K[X]$ is $K(X)$, but $K(\alpha)$ is the smallest field containing $K$ and an $\alpha$ in $F$, a field extension of $K$. Then $K(\alpha_1,\ldots ,\alpha_n)$ should be clear, too. Use wikipedia.

Comment: $K(X)$ is then the set of rational functions over $K$